Kafka consumer stops reading after service restart
A problem that we are facing, where when we restart the consumer pod, the consumer reads approx 150 events and then just stops reading from kafka
This was working fine since 30 days.
problem started when we decided to upscale the DB instance yesterday, for this we manually stopped the pods, upscaled the DB and then restarted the pods.
since restart, everytime I am restarting the service, it reads for some time and then stops reading. I saw producer log, and its writing continuously to this topic
What can be the issue here that I am missing?
Any steps to debug?

You tell us what you've debugged already so we don't repeat any steps you've performed. Please share your service code... maybe there's a bug https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/
